# In-app update API returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE status

Tags: android, android-update-app

I uploaded two bundles to Google Play Console - 19 and 20 code version.
I opened the internal sharing app link of 19 code version of the app and installed it:

[image]

But when I launch the app In-app update API returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE (== 1) status:

[image]

Update is available 100%:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can't just use App bundle explorer

[image]

Though it also has **Internal app sharing link**:

[image]

This one is not going to work though it's also called internal app sharing link...

We have to use this web page to upload apps to test In-app update API https://play.google.com/console/u/2/internal-app-sharing

[image]

Google just made it really bad. Everything is called the same, you can find internal app sharing links from different places but they are not the same